# Dyanmically Adding Buttons to Toolbar in Addon SDK

Tags: button, firefox-addon-sdk

In my script I am reading from a json file and building [sdk menu buttons](https://github.com/willlma/firefox-addon-sdk-menu-button) from the data there.  This works just fine, but I am having trouble adding these buttons to my sdk toolbar.

So, in the loop where I load the data from the json file, I am creating a button from the data and I add the button to an array like this:

```
var alltheButtons = [];
...
alltheButtons.push(jsondata[key].button);
```

In the loop where I create the buttons, I am adding

```
var myToolbar = Toolbar({
    title: "My toolbar",
    items: [alltheButtons]
});
```

However, what happens is that the script errors out when trying to add `alltheButtons` to the toolbar (whence they end up on the regular navbar since they are not attached to any specific toolbar).

The error is this:

```
Message: TypeError: aId.startsWith is not a function
```

So, how do I specify an array of buttons to the toolbar's `items` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myToolbar = Toolbar({
    title: "My toolbar",
    items: alltheButtons
});
```

`items` is supposed to be an `Array` but you are giving it `Array<Array>`

Alternatively you could make use the [ES2015 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var myToolbar = Toolbar({
    title: "My toolbar",
    items: [...alltheButtons, oneMoreButton]
});
```

Comment: @BGM happens to the best of us